# What is the importance of the .DFSFolderLink

Tags: dfs, directory, namespaces

I am currently building a new DFS namespace setup.

My folder E:\CommonStuff\ is already shared on the fileserver.
And now it is also shared as \DOMAIN\CommonStuff

I got 3 questions:

1. I see .DFSFolderLink records in all
   folders I create in the DFS
   Managment console. But all folders
   that was in E:\CommonStuff allready
   does not contain these records.
2. Are the .DFSFolderLink records important?
3. Does it make any difference if I
   create subfolders "the old way" in
   the E:\Commonstuff\ or if I do it
   within the DFS Managment console?

Answer (score 1):

.DFSFolderLink shows up when viewing DFS Links using the Windows 2003 DFS console against Links created on Windows 2008, as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you on the purpose or importance of the DFSFolderLink but to answer #3, no, it does not matter which way you create the folder or share.